# System of equations with multiple answers, but only natural numbers (and other constraints)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, integer-programming

Okay so basically I want the solution with the smallest sum when you add up the integer variable solutions that give a solution to:

$975a + 880b + 790c + 585d + 487e + 440f + 292g + 260h + 530i + 195j + 125k = 1002$

What I mean by this is, say we have one possible solution that's like $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = e = \cdots = j = k = 0$ (which isn't a solution to the problem I gave, of course), the sum of these is $6$. Out of all the possible solutions, I would like the one that gives the smallest sum in this manner.

On top of this, the second restraint(s?) is:

$0 \leq a \leq 27 \\
0 \leq b \leq 37 \\
0 \leq c \leq 14 \\
0 \leq d \leq 15 \\
0 \leq e \leq 1 \\
0 \leq f \leq 2 \\
0 \leq g \leq 1 \\
0 \leq h \leq 6 \\
0 \leq i \leq 1 \\
j \in \mathbb{N} \\
k \in \mathbb{N}$

(So $j$ and $k$ can be any natural number including $0$, and everything else is a natural number within these respective given ranges.)

How would I go about finding this answer with the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Linear optimization problems with integer variables are called "integer (linear) programming" and this one is also a variation on the Knapsack and Bin Packing problems.

The number of possible assignments of the variables is on the order of thousands. That is small enough to check exhaustively without running an IP solver.

Comment: What is an "IP solver"? I don't really know anything about computers

Comment: IP = Integer Programming .  You will probably need some computer calculation for this.  It's possible that some computer algebra system will do it automatically without having to program anything, maybe even Wolfram Alpha can do it given the right command.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems .

Comment: So there is no way to solve this using methods/techniques from pure number theory?

Comment: You might be able to solve it mod $n$ for some $n$ (such as prime powers) and use that to put constraints on the variables.  All but one of the coefficients are divisible by 5, so the equation reduced mod 5 is 2(e-g)=2 or e-g=1 (mod 5).   Given your inequalities that forces g=0 and e=1.  Then apply that to the equation, divide everything by 5 and see if the same trick can be played again.